# Hateoas Post,Put,Delete PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, hateoas

can anybody give example of how to code POST, PUT, Delete Hateoas PHP in Codeigniter, I have 2 tables, author(AuthorID is primary key, BookID I foreign key), book(BookID is primary key)
I have Index_get

```
public function index_get(){
    $id = $this->get('AuthorID');
    $author =[];
    if ($id ==""){
        $data = $this->db->get("author")->result();
        foreach($data as $row=>$key):
        $author[]=["AuthorID"=>$key->AuthorID,
        "AuthorName"=>$key->AuthorName,
        "_link"=>[(object)["href"=>"book/{$key->BookID}",
        "rel"=>"book",
        "type"=>"GET"]],
        "BirthPlace"=>$key->BirthPlace,
        "Email"=>$key->Email,
        "Education"=>$key->Education,
        "Phone"=>$key->Phone,
        "Address"=>$key->Address,
        "Nationality"=>$key->Nationality
    ];
endforeach;
    }
    else {
        $this->db->where("AuthorID","$id");
        $data = $this->db->get("author")->result();
    }
    $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
"code"=>200,
"message"=>"Show Data Success",
"author"=>$author];
$this->response($result, 200);
}
```

and it success

```
"took": 1637045427.669679,
"code": 200,
"message": "Show Data Success",
"author": [
    {
        "AuthorID": "A1",
        "AuthorName": "Jack Dane",
        "_link": [
            {
                "href": "book/1",
                "rel": "book",
                "type": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "BirthPlace": "London",
        "Email": "Jackdane@gmail.com",
        "Education": "Bachelor At Univercity Of Canada",
        "Phone": "09199191",
        "Address": "4457 Grey Fox Farm Road, Houston, Texas",
        "Nationality": "America"
    },
    {
        "AuthorID": "A2",
        "AuthorName": "Michael Dendy",
        "_link": [
            {
                "href": "book/2",
                "rel": "book",
                "type": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "BirthPlace": "New York",
        "Email": "Michaeldendy@gmail.com",
        "Education": "Bachelor At Univercity Of California",
        "Phone": "09188181",
        "Address": "2602 Farnum Road, New York, New York",
        "Nationality": "America"
    },
    {
        "AuthorID": "A3",
        "AuthorName": "Dumando",
        "_link": [
            {
                "href": "book/3",
                "rel": "book",
                "type": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "BirthPlace": "Jakarta",
        "Email": "Dumando@gmail.com",
        "Education": "Bachelor At Indonesia Univercity",
        "Phone": "012929919",
        "Address": "Jl Cendrawaih 919 Jakarta",
        "Nationality": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
        "AuthorID": "A4",
        "AuthorName": "dono",
        "_link": [
            {
                "href": "book/4",
                "rel": "book",
                "type": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "BirthPlace": "Beijing",
        "Email": "dono@gmail.com",
        "Education": "Bachelor at ITS",
        "Phone": "0919191",
        "Address": "Jl. MTHaryono",
        "Nationality": "china"
    }
]
}
```

But when I try to POST in postman it gives me the error "Column 'AuthorID' cannot be null". AuthorID is the primary key.it give me the error "Column 'AuthorID' cannot be null" but AuthorID already has input, I just wanna change BirthPlace.

```
function index_post() {
    $author = array(
                'AuthorID'           => $this->post('AuthorID'),
                'AuthorName'          => $this->post('AuthorName'),
                'BookID'          => $this->post('BookID'),
                'BirthPlace'          => $this->post('BirthPlace'),
                'Email'          => $this->post('Email'),
                'Education'          => $this->post('Education'),
                'Phone'          => $this->post('Phone'),
                'Address'          => $this->post('Address'),
                'Nationality'    => $this->post('Nationality'));

    $insert = $this->db->insert('author', $author);
    if ($insert) {
        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
    "code"=>200,
    "message"=>"Add Data Success",
    "author"=>$author];
    $this->response($result, 200);
    } else {
        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
    "code"=>200,
    "message"=>"Failed Add Data",
    "author"=>$author];
    $this->response($result, 502);
    }
}
```

when I try PUT in postman it give me success message but the data is not update. AuthorID is null, BoodID is null, i already input AuthorID, BookID in postman and still data cannot update,

```
function index_put() {
    $id = $this->put('AuthorID');
    $author = array(
        'AuthorID'           => $this->put('AuthorID'),
        'AuthorName'          => $this->put('AuthorName'),
        'BookID'          => $this->put('BookID'),
        'BirthPlace'          => $this->put('BirthPlace'),
        'Email'          => $this->put('Email'),
        'Education'          => $this->put('Education'),
        'Phone'          => $this->put('Phone'),
        'Address'          => $this->put('Address'),
        'Nationality'    => $this->put('Nationality'));
    $this->db->where('AuthorID', $id);
    $update = $this->db->update('author', $author);
    if ($update) {
        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
    "code"=>200,
    "message"=>"Data Update Success",
    "author"=>$author];
    $this->response($result, 200);
    } else {
        $result = ["took"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],
        "code"=>200,
        "message"=>"Failed Update Data",
        "author"=>$author];
        $this->response($result, 502);
    }
}
```

result index_put

```
{
"took": 1637045848.425828,
"code": 200,
"message": "Data Update Success",
"author": {
    "AuthorID": null,
    "AuthorName": "Jack Dane",
    "BookID": null,
    "BirthPlace": "Jakarta",
    "Email": "Jackdane@gmail.com",
    "Education": "Bachelor At Univercity Of Canada",
    "Phone": "09199191",
    "Address": "4457 Grey Fox Farm Road, Houston, Texas",
    "Nationality": "America"
}
```

}

and when I try DELETE it gives me "status": "Success Delete Data" but the data is not removed when I check in PHPMyAdmin.

```
function index_delete() {
    $id = $this->delete('AuthorID');
    $this->db->where('AuthorID', $id);
    $delete = $this->db->delete('author');
    if ($delete) {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'Success Delete Data'), 200);
    } 
    
    else{
        $this->response(array('status' => 'fail Delete Data', 502));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to check for `null` values manually. If such a value is received, don't add the corresponing key to the array of values to be updated

Comment: for index_put right?, I remove AuthorID,BookID in array,  the value did receive in result json but database is not update, so when i use GET. the value didnt update. can you help?

Comment: "Database is not update" - what does that mean? What have you tried to check **why** this is not working?

Comment: i mean when i check the table in phpmyadmin, the value didnt change. for example when i use put in postman i change AuthorName"jack" to AuthorName"denis", the array in json change but in phpmyadmin didnt change